# For an Android app, how do I read a string from an *.xml file?

Tags: android, string, arrays

Let's start with the Hello World program detailed at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html .

Let's add the file res/values/arrayfile.xml .  Unfortunately, Stack Overflow refuses to display the tags, so I'll describe what's in this file.  There are two string-arrays, one named "trees" and one named "bondactors".  The items under the singers category are (in order): "oak", "willow", "maple", and "birch".  The items under the bondactors category are (in order): "Sean Connery", "George Lazenby", "Roger Moore", "Pierce Brosnan", and "Daniel Craig".

Let's modify the HelloAndroid.java file so that it can display any of the items listed in res/values/arrayfile.xml .

How do I get the Android app to print "Pierce Brosnan" in place of "Hello, Android"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] bondactors = res.getStringArray(R.array.bondactors_array);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks.  And I now see that bondactors[0], bondactors[1], etc. gives me the name of a specific Bond actor.